# SQL Developer: Add the number of books sold. If no books were sold, you must show a zero

Tags: sql, oracle, null, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need to show the books that did not get any sales. There are 14 books in all. I only get 11. I am not sure if I need to use rollup to show the nulls as 0 or something else. ISNULL is not working in the table. Below is my attempt to get the results.

```
select  b.ISBN
    ,  b.TITLE
    ,  b.RETAIL
    ,  b.COST
    ,  round(sum((b.RETAIL- b.COST)/b.COST*100),2)||'%' "Profit Percentage"  
    ,  count(*) as "Book Count" 
 from  BOOKS b   
    ,  ORDERITEMS oi
    ,  ORDERS o 
where  b.ISBN = oi.ISBN
and    oi.ORDER# = o.ORDER#  
group by(b.ISBN, b.TITLE, b.RETAIL, b.COST)
;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query won't return information for books which have't been ordered. The implied joins you're using, with multiple tables listed in the `FROM` clause, function as an *inner* join, meaning that data for each book must be present in all three tables for any data to be returned by the query. You need to use an *outer* join to have data returned if it doesn't exist in all tables:

```
select  b.ISBN
    ,  b.TITLE
    ,  b.RETAIL
    ,  b.COST
    ,  round(sum((b.RETAIL- b.COST)/b.COST*100),2)||'%' "Profit Percentage"  
    ,  count(*) as "Book Count" 
  from  BOOKS b   
  LEFT OUTER JOIN ORDERITEMS oi
    ON oi.ISBN = b.ISBN
  LEFT OUTER JOIN ORDERS o 
    ON o.ORDER# = oi.ORDER#
  group by(b.ISBN, b.TITLE, b.RETAIL, b.COST)
```